# Jquery animate not working when used inside a function passing parmeters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This is the peice of code that I want to run to animate any css property with the same function.

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

<div class='box'></div>

function animateDimension(el, dimension, value, callback) {
    var $el = $(el);
    callback = callback || function() {};
    $el.animate({
    dimension : value,
    },1000, callback);
}
```

Calling this function -

```
animateDimension($('.box'),'width',0, function(){
    $('.box').hide();
});
```

The box hides after one second but the width does not change. Can someone help  me out???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
function animateDimension($el, dimension, value, callback) {
    var properties = {};
    properties[dimension] = value;
    callback = callback || $.noop;
    $el.animate(properties, 1000, callback);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7afFH/ (Thx @vjs for jsfiddle!)

Comment: Thanks a ton :)Making an object and passing it to animate works, what made my code not do what it ws supposed to?

Comment: Because you need to use literal notation of object here for passing key as variable string. In your code, you were setting a `dimension` property

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change width is

`function animateDimension(el, dimension, value, callback) {
    var $el = $(el);
    callback = callback || function() {};
    $el.animate({
    width : value,
    },1000, callback);
}`

`animateDimension($('.box'),'width','0px', function(){
    $('.box').hide();
    alert($('.box').css('width'))
});`

Here is demo
http://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthShah/M3Kzh/